How can I display a Highlight / Ripple effect when double tapping on an Inkwell ? The effect is only shown when tapped once
My issue is that the highlight effect is only shown when I single tap the Inkwell, but I want it to show when I double-tap (only on double-tap in this case to like a comment), but nothing is displayed.
The double-tap callback is triggered as expected.
I'm using an Inkwell widget inside a ListView in my Flutter app to create a CommentCard widget.
return InkWell(
      onDoubleTap: () {
        likeComment(ref);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 10),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                openProfile(context, ref, comment.uid);
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(comment.profilePic),
                radius: 18,
              ),
            ),

I expected a way to show the highlight when double-tapping.
